# Python Pandas Fillna Median not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to fill all the nans in a dataframe containing multiple columns and several rows. I am using this to train a multi variate ML-model so I want to fill the nans for each column with the median. Just to test the median function I did this:

```
training_df.loc[[0]] = np.nan # Sets first row to nan
print(training_df.isnull().values.any()) # Prints true because we just inserted nans
test = training_df.fillna(training_df.median()) # Fillna with median
print(test.isnull().values.any()) # Check afterwards
```

But when I do this nothing happens, the print of the last row still returns True. If I try to change to use the median function like this instead:

```
training_df.fillna(training_df.median(), inplace=True)
```

Nothing happens as well. If I do this:

```
training_df = training_df.fillna(training_df.median(), inplace=True)
```

Training_df becomes none. How can I solve this?

Comment: First thing I would do is check the data types of `training_df` using `training_df.info()`. The behaviour you've described can happen if you have any columns not stored as numeric types.

Comment: Also, when you use `inplace=True`, don't assign the result to a variable, as it will always be `None`. That's why your last line sets the whole variable to `None`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @thesilkworm suggested, convert your series to numeric first. Below is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                   [5, 1, 2, 'hello'],
                   [1, 4, 3, 4],
                   [9, 8, 7, 6]], dtype=object)

df = df.fillna(df.median())  # fails

df[df.columns] = df[df.columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

df = df.fillna(df.median())  # works
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.nanmedian` + a dict comprehension to rename.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,np.nan,3], "col2": [5, np.nan, 10, np.nan]})

col_map = {df.columns.get_loc(col):col for col in df.columns} # {0: "col1", 1: "col2"}
median_values = pd.Series(np.nanmedian(df, axis=0)).rename(col_map)
df = df.fillna(median_values)

>> df
   col1 col2
0   1.0 5.0
1   2.0 7.5
2   2.0 10.0
3   3.0 7.5
```

You can see that the intermittent step in jpp's answer of calling `df.median()` after `.apply()` is the same as the `median_series` I've defined above.

```
print(df.median()) # after .apply()
col1    2.0
col2    7.5
dtype: float64

print(median_series)
col1    2.0
col2    7.5
dtype: float64
```

**Note**: You'll get an error using `np.nanmedian` if one of the values in your df is a string like "hi", which we often want in production.

**Explanation:**
I still like the answer by jpp for most cases, but sometimes if my data is enormous or I'm sending data to an ML API Endpoint I don't want to use `errors='coerce'` to blanket over everything and **do** want to return an error. Imagine the scenario you're in production 6 months later and some of your `col1` values are being passed as strings: `[1, 2, 'hi', 'bye']`. Using `errors=coerce` will set `hi` & `bye` to `NaN`. You'll be unaware that strings are leaking into the column from some upstream change you didn't make and your ML algorithm is passing out scores like normal, but in reality it's just scoring a bunch of NaNs. Your model performance will degrade without knowing why and in reality it's a good model it's just not scoring on correct data. Company loses money, you're fired. I realize I digressed down an unlikely slippery slope but wanted to pack the emphasis.

We **want** this error if in prod:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,np.nan,'hi'], "col2": [5, np.nan, 10, np.nan]})
col_map = {df.columns.get_loc(col):col for col in df.columns} # {0: "col1", 1: "col2"}
median_series = pd.Series(np.nanmedian(df, axis=0)).rename(col_map)
>> TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```